# pdf & docx file doent open on browser console from s3 buket

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to open PDF and document files from my S3 bucket by clicking on the S3 URLs.
[image]

To troubleshoot, I performed a test by uploading the same file manually, and this time the PDF file opened correctly in the browser console. However, when using a PHP script to upload the same file, attempting to open the file from the browser resulted in an error message stating 'An error occurred.'

I have verified that the second PDF file loaded using the PHP script is not corrupted, and I can confirm that the file type has been correctly set during the upload process.